# Cocos2D Object extending CCSprite Android

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2D and I have created an Object class that extends CCSprite

I need to call call the CCSprite.sprite("filename") method not as a CCSprite but as the Object class I created.

Here is my class

```
public class Object extends CCSprite{
    public Object(){

    }
}
```

Here is how I am trying to call the method

```
protected GameLayer()
{
    Object player = new Object();   
    player = Object.sprite("player.png");
{
```

I am getting an error saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from CCSprite to Object"

Since the class is a child of CCSprite why does it need to be coverted?

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an `Object` class defined that is the superclass of everything. You can't go and redefine it, because then the compiler gets confused.

Comment: Ok. I have changed it so I have now created a class MyObject. and I am still having the same problem?
Do I need to do something different?